# (Upper bound on) Tree width of an $n \times n$ grid graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, trees

Given any $n \geq 1$ consider the $n \times n$ grid graph.

For example, for $n = 3$, this looks like:

$$\begin{matrix}1&-&2&-&3\\|&&|&&|\\4&-&5&-&6\\|&&|&&|\\7&-&8&-&9\end{matrix}$$

The [tree width](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treewidth) has a somewhat roundabout definition. The way we did it it: consider any ordering on the vertices- and then remove the vertices one by one; every time you remove a vertex add an edge between the neighbors of the vertex being removed. Then this gives you a bunch of new edges based on the ordering of the vertices. Then combine the new edges with the old edges- the elimination width with respect to this ordering is the maximal clique with this new augmented edge set. The tree width is the least possible edge set.

So yeah, a bit convoluted- but I think there's a bunch of different definitions and whichever is fine.

I would like to find an upper bound on the tree width for the $n \times n$ grid. Obviously I would like a reasonable upper bound, something less than $n^2$ which is the biggest possible clique with these vertices.

I'm pretty sure intuitively that the tree width is actually $n + 1$ exactly - this can be seen by eliminating the vertices by iteratingly removing the corners of the grid. So in the $3 \times 3$ grid you first remove the corners $1, 3, 7, 9$ and then you get a new graph and remove those corners $2, 4, 8, 6$ and so on. This adds minimal edges and so this elimination width will witness the tree width. In the case of $3 \times 3$ one can easily check that the maximal clique is indeed $4 = 3 + 1$.

But I am unable to prove it for general $n$.

I merely need a (reasonable) upper bound however, so I'm fine with just that if proving the exact value is too involved.

Any ideas?

Comment: If [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/63068) is correct it should be exactly $n$.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the gride 3x3 consider the tree descomposición given by the path $P_{6}=t_{1}\cdots t_{6}$, where $t_{i}=\{i,i+1,i+2,i+3\}$ for $i=1,\cdots ,6$. Thus the tree width is ≤3.

Indeed, in any nxn grid we can check that the tw is n.